# Why is hibernate still disabled by default? (Is it safe to use hibernation?)

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

I remember 10 years ago hibernate was not working as on Windows systems. It would sometimes work, sometimes it would crash.

But 2014 is almost ended, and hibernate is still not enabled by default.

*Is hibernate still unsafe or not recommended to use in Ubuntu?*

Comment: Doesn't hibernate still attempt to write all ram to disk, then shutdown? And later attempt to "read" everything back into ram & keep running as it was before? I think it's been advertised for more than 10 years, and I think it's never really worked as good as advertised, not worth the 30sec-1 minute difference in boot time at least imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **safe** to use hibernation on Ubuntu.  It's just *not tested* on all hardware out there...  Micro$oft has much more money then Canonical and can test many more machines (or have the vendors themselves test it for them as they have a near market-monopoly)

Comment: For anyone feeling uneasy about hibernation should feel even more uneasy about suspend. After all it is similar function (halt the PC and continue at a later stage) without backup on disk, therefore energy supply is crucial. However to get a better feeling both hibernation and suspend can be tested on Linus, just follow https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/basic-pm-debugging.html