# Why isn't hibernation available by default in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, hibernate

I've been searching how to hibernate on Ubuntu 20 and found things like:

[How to enable hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)

[Hibernation in Kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231631/hibernation-in-kubuntu-20-04)

Although it's not so hard to do, let's not forget that Ubuntu is a widely popular distribution and some of its users might be insecure following instructions like these. Instead, why not providing a simple hibernation button you might activate from the settings? It's that so hard to provide?

I also found this question [Why is hibernate still disabled by default? (Is it safe to use hibernation?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561727/why-is-hibernate-still-disabled-by-default-is-it-safe-to-use-hibernation), which is a bit old,
arguing it's all because Canonical can't test hibernation in all computer models from all vendors, so they can't guarantee it will work. Still, they could provide the option maybe with some warning.

Does anyone has inside knowledge about this?

Don't get me wrong, I love Ubuntu, that's precisely why I would like it to be as functional as possible.

Comment: Why would one want to be able to "hibernate" a server farm? Setting up hibernation uses resources, and imposes policy restraints. Not all Ubuntus are Just Like Yours.

Comment: Install `pm-tools` and read `dpkg  -L pm-tools`.

Comment: In general, NEVER follow internet instructions until you understand what they do,  how it will affect your system, how to UNDO.

Comment: I've never hibernated on Linux but I hear it doesn't work very well. Suspend works OK and I use it all the time. Other than that one can simply power off and then power on when needed. With the speed of modern day SSD's power off / on again is not so much an inconvenience anymore.

Comment: I have been usin hibernation on bootable uSB sticks, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247133/how-to-handle-full-install-usb-and-swap-space. I can hibernate, remove the stick and plug it back in without loosing my place. Setting up hibernation is not too difficult.

Comment: The great thing about Linux is that you can modify it. If anything, fewer defaults is better.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu is not all about server farms. There is a distribution called Ubuntu Desktop, it comes with Gnome. The big advantage is for innocent users. So I second the idea there should be some simple mechanism to activate hibernation.